# Why does Scala script fail if CLASSPATH is set?

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala 2.10 script that works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

classpath="${CLASSPATH}"
unset CLASSPATH

exec ${SCALA_HOME}/bin/scala -cp "${classpath}" "$0" "$@" 2>&1
!#

import stuff
```

But when `CLASSPATH` isn't `unset`, it fails with stuff like:

```
$ ./setter-for-catan.scala
./setter-for-catan.scala:12: error: not found: object play
import play.api.libs.json.JsArray
       ^

one error found
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some funky state leftover from the compiler daemon. Try `fsc -shutdown` or `scala -nc` to reset the daemon.

Comment: What? I answered your question and you didn't bestow the green check? Although I find scala tooling intrinsically interesting, this situation says to me, "I don't need your help."

Comment: @som-snytt, PathResolver did NOT resolve the problem. Copy the answer I posted here and I'll delete mine and check yours (if the system still allows me to do so). You'll also note that I DID check your comment that led to my answer and I specifically asked that you create your own answer. I waited for such an answer from you but never saw one (instead you commented 'So happy for you') so I created my own. I'm grateful for your help and would gladly give you the credit for it.

Comment: @som-snytt, BTW, I tried tagging you in my comments, but SO seems to wipe out the tags if it's directed towards the answer owner.

Answer (score 3):

The scala script has a modest `-debug` option.

Use `-Ylog-classpath` to see what the compiler is using.

Use `-nc` to say "no compile server daemon".

Use `fsc -shutdown` to start over.

Package changes are anathema, so unexpected dirs in the path with package names, or old package objects, etc, cause inexplicable build problems.

Use `PathResolver` to dump what classpath it sees.

An empty directory with your package name can interfere with package discovery.

```
${SCALA_HOME}/bin/scala -cp "${classpath}" scala.tools.util.PathResolver
${SCALA_HOME}/bin/scala -cp "${classpath}" scala.tools.util.PathResolver some-args
```

You'll see something like:

```
apm@mara:~/tmp/scripts$ ./foo.sh
object Environment {
  scalaHome          = /media/Software/scala-2.10.1 (useJavaClassPath = true)
  javaBootClassPath  = <1122 chars>
  javaExtDirs        = 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext
/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
  javaUserClassPath  = ""
  scalaExtDirs       = 
}
object Defaults {
  scalaHome            = /media/Software/scala-2.10.1
  javaBootClassPath    = 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/netx.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/plugin.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rhino.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jfr.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/classes
/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/akka-actors.jar
/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/jline.jar
/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/scala-actors.jar
/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/scala-actors-migration.jar
/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/scala-compiler.jar
/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/scala-library.jar
/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/scala-partest.jar
/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/scalap.jar
/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/scala-reflect.jar
/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/scala-swing.jar
/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/typesafe-config.jar
  scalaLibDirFound     = Some(/media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib)
  scalaLibFound        = /media/Software/scala-2.10.1/lib/scala-library.jar
  scalaBootClassPath   = 
  scalaPluginPath      = /media/Software/scala-2.10.1/misc/scala-devel/plugins
}
 COMMAND: 'scala some-args'
RESIDUAL: 'scala some-args'
```

Comment: I added a call to PathResolver -debug before and after the unset CLASSPATH. There's absolutely no difference between the two.

Comment: @NoelYap  Also try scala -nc -Ylog-classpath, where -nc ignores the external compiler; or fsc -shutdown. Maybe you're just dealing with compile state, since it says "object play" (not value play).

Comment: `-nc` worked. Then I removed it and the script still worked. Perhaps `-nc` reset whatever funky state the daemon was in?