# Package changes ignored when executing modular/multi-file scala as a shell script

Tags: shell, scala, shebang

When I have a scala program as a shell script that pulls from a package, if I modify that package, the shell script can't see the changes, even though I recompiled.

Here is a very simple example:

`one.scala`:

```
package myPackage
object one {
  val value = "one"
}
```

`main.scala`:

```
import myPackage._
object Main extends App {
  println( one.value )
}
```

Now, if I run it as follows, everything works as you would expect:

```
$ scalac one.scala main.scala
$ scala Main
one
```

Now I turn `main.scala` into a shell script

```
#/usr/bin/env scala
import myPackage._
println( one.value )
```

and execute it

```
$ chmod 755 main.scala
$ ./main.scala
one
```

Everything appears fine, until I modify the package and try to reference it

`two.scala`:

```
package myPackage
object two {
  val value = "two"
}
```

and modify my main to reference it:

```
#/usr/bin/env scala
import myPackage._
println( one.value )
println( two.value )
```

Now compile and run it and get a strange error message:

```
$ scalac one.scala two.scala
$ ./main.scala
.../main.scala:4: error: not found: value two
println( two.value )
         ^
```

But it's in there.  It's just not picking it up for some reason.  So let's try changing main back...

```
//#!/usr/bin/env scala
import myPackage._
object Main extends App {
  println( one.value )
  println( two.value )
}
```

And compile and run

```
$ scalac one.scala two.scala main.scala
$ scala Main
one
two
```

Now convert it back to running under the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala
import myPackage._
//object Main extends App {
  println( one.value )
  println( two.value )
//}
```

And run it:

```
$ scalac one.scala two.scala
$ ./main.scala
.../main.scala:4: error: not found: value two
println( two.value )
         ^
```

SAY WHAT?! What is going on here?  And how do I fix it?

I've tried it with CLASSPATH= and ="." and =`pwd`

I tried modifying the shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala -cp . "$0" "$@"
!#
```

And it runs:

```
$ ./main.scala
one
two
```

Very interesting.  So it picked up the change.  Now let's change the package again

`one.scala`

```
package myPackage
object one {
  val value = "one"
  val and = "and
}
```

`main.scala`

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala -cp . "$0" "$@"
!#
import myPackage._
//object Main extends App {
    println( one.value )
    println( one.and )
    println( two.value )
//}
```

Which again exhibits the error, effectively:

```
./main.scala:8: error: value and is not a member of object myPackage.one
println( one.and )
             ^
```

So, change the shebang back.  No dice.  Try a different shebang.  Not helping.  But if I run it as a Class, it works.

Can anyone else reproduce this?  Any ideas on what is happening here?

```
$ uname -a
Darwin <hostname> 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.1 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scala -nc` to avoid running the compile daemon.

This is probably a duplicate.

AIA if I'm mistaken because ;tldr syndrome.

Comment: That solved the problem.  Thank you.  I looked all over trying to find something to tell me, but I couldn't find anything, so I asked.  Such is the joy of not knowing what to search for.

Comment: I picked up my kid when she was in the middle of folding an origami Pikachu. She said that's OK, we can look it up online. I said I wouldn't know what to google for. But "Origami p" autocompletes. "site:stackoverflow.com scala script package ignored" yields http://stackoverflow.com/a/17416175/1296806 which wasn't a happy SO experience for me personally. I'm glad this answer was short and sweet. Sorry for your loss of time, though.